# iPhone accessibility and multi-touch gestures with voice over on

Tags: iphone, accessibility

In my iPhone application, I am using multi-touch gestures for user interaction.

Is there any way to get multi-touch gestures when accessibility voiceover is ON?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [this](http://help.apple.com/iphone/3/voiceover/en/iphddd0d7ae.html) it is possible to pass jestures through voiceover although I haven't had to do this yet. If you'd like to ask questions of blind iphone users and possibly find testers for your application you can subscribe to the [VIPhone](http://groups.google.com/group/viphone) google group.